# Difference betweenJavaScript object types

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm new to OOP, but I got some understanding of it. In JavaScript however I am able to define object in 3 separate ways and I was wondering which is the right way and perhaps why? To illustrate what I am talking about I have the following code that outputs *test1*, *test2*, *test3* into the console (it's not supposed to be identical, but merely showing the different ways to define more or less the same objects):

```
<script>
    let Player = {
        name: "test1",

        hello: function () {
            console.log(this.name)
        }
    }
    Player.hello();
//==============
    class Playa {
        constructor() {
            this.name = "test2";
        }
        hey() {
            console.log(this.name);
        }
    }
    var p2 = new Playa();
    p2.hey();
//==============
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Person.prototype.howdy = function () {
        console.log(this.name);
    };

    var p3 = new Person("test3");
    p3.howdy();
</script>
```

Comment: They're all OK. If you have tens of thousands of objects, method 1 will be less efficient than others in some engines.

Comment: If I were you, I’d go for second way with classes

Comment: Method 1 is a `singleton object` and will be consumed/shared with all its users. 
Method 2,3 are like `factory objects` which provide a base template for you to create a custom object which has a pre-defined set of methods to ease your data management.